# Shorter way to get an iterator for a std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, std, stdvector

Lets say that I have got a vector like this.

```
std::vector<a_complicated_whatever_identifier *> *something
    = new std::vector<a_complicated_whatever_identifier *>;
// by the way, is this the right way to do this?
```

Now I want to get an iterator for this... so I would do this like this.

```
std::vector<a_complicated_whatever_identifier *>::iterator iter;
```

But I find it a little too much for my code. I wonder, is there any more, brief way to ask for an iterator regardless of the type?

I was thinking in something like.

```
something::iterator iter;
    // OK, don’t laugh at me, I am still beginning with C++
```

Well, it obviously fail, but I guess you get the idea. How to accomplish this or something similar?

Comment: That's what `typedef`s are for.

Comment: We usually write just `std::vector<a_complicated_whatever_identifier *> something;`. Compared to Java,  C++ rarely uses `new`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a typedef.

```
typedef std::vector<complicated *>::iterator complicated_iter
```

Then set them like this:

```
complicated_iter begin, end;
```

Comment: `std::vector<complicated *>::iter`? What is it?

Comment: Whoops, corrected. I'm used to calling iterators "iter" for variables.

Answer (score 11):

You would typically give your *containers* sensible typedefs, and then it's a breeze:

```
typedef std::pair<int, Employee> EmployeeTag;
typedef std::map<Foo, EmployeeTag> SignInRecords;

for (SignInRecords::const_iterator it = clock_ins.begin(); ... )
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Usually, having a handy typedef for the container is more practical and self-documenting that an explicit typedef for the iterator (imagine if you're changing the container).

With the new C++ (11), you can say `auto it = clock_ins.cbegin()` to get a const-iterator.

Answer (score 7):

In C++11 you'll be able to use `auto`.

```
auto iter = my_container.begin();
```

In the meantime just use a typedef for the vector:

```
typedef std::vector<a_complicated_whatever_identifier *> my_vector;
my_vector::iterator iter = my_container.begin();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should *rarely* have much need/use for defining an iterator directly. In particular, iterating through a collection should normally be done by a generic algorithm. If there's one already defined that can do the job, it's best to use it. If there's not, it's best to write your own algorithm *as an algorithm*. In this case, the iterator type becomes a template parameter with whatever name you prefer (usually something referring at least loosely to the iterator category):

```
template <class InputIterator>
void my_algorithm(InputIterator start, InputIterator stop) { 
    for (InputIterator p = start; p != stop; ++p) 
        do_something_with(*p);
}
```

Since they've been mentioned, I'll point out that IMO, `typedef` and C++11's new `auto` are (at least IMO) rarely a good answer to this situation. Yes, they can eliminate (or at least reduce) the verbosity in defining an object of the iterator type -- but in this case, it's basically just treating the symptom, not the disease.

As an aside, I'd also note that:

1. A vector of pointers is usually a mistake.
2. Dynamically allocating a vector is even more likely a mistake.

At least right off, it looks rather as if you're probably accustomed to something like Java, where you *always* have to use `new` to create an object. In C++, this is relatively unusual -- most of the time, you want to just define a local object so creation and destruction will be handled automatically.

Comment: I have never coded in Java, I am using a vector of pointers, and with new keyword, because it will store references to instances of a certain class (it will be for a static member of the class), and the number of objects will be determined only at runtime. They can be from **1** up to **OVER NINE THOUSAND**!!!
So, I guess that is the way to do it.

Comment: @Mario: None of that seems to justify either dynamic allocation of the vector, *or* its containing pointers. If anything, it sounds like just the opposite. And, BTW, "over 9 thousand" objects in a collection hardly qualifies for an exclamation point at all, not to mention three; up to hundreds of millions of objects is pretty routine, and billions (read as "milliards" if you use that) is hardly unheard of.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks, but I think I'm just as happy not knowing anything about "dragonball". In any case, the reasoning seems to lack validity -- the reason to use a pointer(-like class) would be shared access to a common group of items; the number of items is mostly irrelevant.

Comment: @Jerry : Indeed, I agree that storing pointers seems unnecessary here; I was only pointing out the meaning of the meme.

Comment: @ildjarn: No problem -- and if my comment sounded hostile about it, I apologize.

Comment: @Jerry so what would be a better approach than mine? Why is it pointless to store pointers and why is new not necessarily the best way for this?

Comment: @MArio: usually you just want to store objects. You define the vector as a member object, not a pointer to one -- a vector is already primarily a pointer with a couple of extra pieces for bookkeeping (size of current allocation, size in use, *maybe* one or two other things, but usually that's about it -- sizeof(vector) is often 12 on a 32-bit machine).

Comment: @Jerry in this case my plan is to store references to the objects, and this static member wont be the only one doing that, there will be other classes referring to some instances too. Are pointers in this case wrong too?

Comment: @Mario: multiple references to the same data *is* a good argument for something that least pointer-like -- but a raw pointer is only rarely the best way to handle that. In particular, it only works well if you assure that the data will never be destroyed until after all the other pointers to it are. Otherwise, you're generally better off with something like a `weak_ptr` that can detect when it's referring to stale data.

Answer (score 0):

> // by the way, is this the right way to do this?

What you are doing is correct. The best approach depends on how you want to use that vector.

> But I find it a little too much for my code. I wonder, is there any
>   more, brief way to ask for an iterator regardless of the type?

Yes, you can define the vector as a type:

```
typedef std::vector<a_complicated_whatever_identifier *> MyVector;
MyVector * vectPtr = new MyVector;
MyVector::iterator iter;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recent compiler, I suggest giving c++11 a spin. Most compilers support it in the form of the `--std=c++0x` flag. You can do all kinds of nifty things related to type inference:

```
std::list<std::map<std::string, some_complex_type> > tables;

for (auto& table: tables)
{
     std::cout << table.size() << std::endl;
}

for (auto it = tables.begin(); it!= tables.end(); ++it)
{
     std::cout << it->size() << std::endl;
}
```

Also look at decltype and many other handyness:

```
// full copy is easy
auto clone = tables; 

// but you wanted same type, no data?
decltype(tables) empty;
```

Contrived example of combining typedefs with the above:

```
typedef decltype(tables) stables_t;
typedef stables_t::value_type::const_iterator ci_t;
```

Comment: I think you mean `table.second.size()`, `it->second.size()`, and `stables_t::mapped_type::const_iterator`.

Comment: @ildjarn: oops, yes, thank you. Switched horses midway through the writing. Fixing it.

Comment: with c++ 11 and beyond there are also type aliases which can be used instead of `typedef` example:`using stables_t = decltype(tables);`